# How to use containers in Firefox v85?

Tags: linux, firefox, gentoo, multi-account-containers

I have Firefox version `85.0.2-r1`, but I am unable to use containers.  I tried to install the [multi-account container](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search) add-on, but I see nothing.  I'm using Gentoo Linux.

```
www-client/firefox-85.0.2-r1:0/85::gentoo  USE="clang gmp-autoupdate openh264 pulseaudio system-av1 system-harfbuzz system-icu system-jpeg system-libevent system-libvpx system-webp -dbus -debug -eme-free -geckodriver -hardened -hwaccel -jack -lto -pgo -screencast (-selinux) -wayland -wifi" L10N="en-GB -ach -af -an -ar -ast -az -be -bg -bn -br -bs -ca -ca-valencia -cak -cs -cy -da -de -dsb -el -en-CA -eo -es-AR -es-CL -es-ES -es-MX -et -eu -fa -ff -fi -fr -fy -ga -gd -gl -gn -gu -he -hi -hr -hsb -hu -hy -ia -id -is -it -ja -ka -kab -kk -km -kn -ko -lij -lt -lv -mk -mr -ms -my -nb -ne -nl -nn -oc -pa -pl -pt-BR -pt-PT -rm -ro -ru -si -sk -sl -son -sq -sr -sv -ta -te -th -tl -tr -trs -uk -ur -uz -vi -xh -zh-CN -zh-TW" 27 KiB
```

What I did:

- Installed add-on above.
- Pressed `Ctrl + .` (without plus key, just control then period).
- Right click on a tab to see if there is any container related menu.

But I see nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Open *Settings → General* and make sure *Enable Container Tabs* is visible and checked. That confirms that containers are enabled.

- Right-click the `+` button that opens a new tab. A container choice menu should appear.
- Right-click menu of an existing tab should have a *Reopen in Container* item.
- Extension's button in the navigation bar should also provide access to these features.
- Configuring a site to always open in a container is available through the button too.

Comment: Do I also have to have the add-on?  Or does it work without any add-ons?

Comment: @caveman IIRC if you don't have any addons that make use of containers, that checkbox will disappear from Settings altogether.

Comment: Right, I see that when add-on is installed, but I do not see "_Reopen in Container_" item on right-menu of tabs, nor the right-menu on `+`.